# React Native optimize the code to render the correct tag

Tags: react-native

I tried to optimize this little code but i didn't found anything that works well. My goal is to optimize it only for the sake of readability.

```
_renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
        case 'Biotiful':
            return ( <Home navigator={navigator} route={route} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'ProdottoPreferiti':
            return ( <Prodotto {...route.passProps} { ...this.props}  navigator={navigator} route={route} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Camera':
            return ( <Camera navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} route={route} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Istruzioni':
            return ( <Istruzioni navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} route={route} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Prodotto':
            return ( <Prodotto {...route.passProps} { ...this.props}  navigator={navigator} route={route} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Profilo':
            return ( <Profilo {...route.passProps} { ...this.props}  navigator={navigator} route={route} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Webview':
            return ( <Webview {...route.passProps} { ...this.props}  navigator={navigator} route={route} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Impostazioni':
            return ( <Impostazioni navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Preferiti':
            return ( <Preferiti navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'BarCode':
            return ( <BarCode navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'ChiSiamo':
            return ( <ChiSiamo navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'NuovoProdotto':
            return ( <NuovoProdotto navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
        case 'Suggerimento':
            return ( <Suggerimento navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/> );
    }
}
```

I attempted to put a dynamic tag name using the `route.id`, but it cannot be done, or at least i didn't found a way to do it.

Someone can see a better way to do it? More compact?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about creating a global Routes array at the top like this

```
import LandingScreen from 'src/screens/landingScreen';
import Login from 'src/screens/login'
import SignUp from 'src/screens/signUp'
import ForgotPassword from 'src/screens/forgotPassword'
import UserProfile from 'src/screens/userProfile'

//everything is pretty similar to yours but I just moved everything to the top and outside of _renderScene function    
let Routes ={
      landingScreen:LandingScreen,
      login:Login,
      signUp:SignUp,
      forgotPassword:ForgotPassword,
      userProfile:UserProfile
    }
```

and then just using this simple line of code in renderSecene to get it Run

```
_renderScene(route, navigator) {
      const Component = Routes[route.Name]
      return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/>
  }
```

it may not be the best solution but I am doing pretty fine with this in my app

this is how my navigator looks

```
<Navigator
                    ref="navigator"
                    configureScene={(route) => {
                       return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid;
                    }}
                    initialRoute={{Name :'landingScreen'}}
                    renderScene={this._renderScene}
                  />
```

you can simply push scenes to stack by doing like this

```
this.props.navigator.push({Name :'userProfile', ...props, ...states});
```

this single line can remove the screen out of stack

```
this.props.navigator.pop({Name :'userProfile'});
//this.props.navigator.pop(0);   will remove the current scene
```

******I will suggest you to better use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) or [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) you will get better native feel and smooth transitions

Comment: I'm getting a strange behaviour:
`_renderScene(route, navigator) {
      const Component = "Home"
      return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} { ...this.props} emitter= {_emitter}/>
}` will lead to this behaviour : `expected a component class got object object`. If i replace `<Component` with `<Home` everything works well. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: see if you have followed all the step of mine then you have to do like const Component = Routes[route.Name] , I had saved all the pages to my Routes array beforehand